# How does pattern matching work in exists function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

This code from book "Functional programming in scala"

```
sealed trait Stream[+A] {
  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = this match {
    case Cons(h, t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
    case _ => z
  }

  def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = foldRight(false)((a, b) => p(a) || b)
}

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

I don't understand what is it `a` and `b` in `exists` func? How scala match arguments to `foldRight`

Comment: `a` and `b` are the parameters declared by your lambda. The function that you are passing is `f`, the `foldRight` function calls it with two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foldRight` and `foldLeft` operates over a collection (stream in your example), receives two parameters (base value) and a function. This function receives also two parameters an accumulator and a element, which process in each iteration

The accumulator is in the side of the fold (i.e. to the right in `foldRight` and to the left in `foldLeft`), so in your case `b` is the accumulator.

The accumulator is initialized as the default value (`false` in your example)

The other parameter (`a` in your example) is each element of the stream over which you iterate.

In this case (`exists`) will iterate until an element satisfied the predicate p, otherwise it will keep iterating until it reaches the end of the `Stream`

**From the API**

> `def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) ⇒ B): B` Applies a binary operator to
>   all elements of this sequence and a start value, going right to left.
>
> Note: will not terminate for infinite-sized collections.
>
> `B the result type of the binary operator.`
>
> `z the start value.`
>
> `op the binary operator.`
>
> returns the result of inserting op between consecutive elements of
>   this sequence, going right to left with the start value z on the
>   right:
>
> `op(x_1, op(x_2, ... op(x_n, z)...))` where `x1, ..., xn` are the elements
>   of this sequence. Returns z if this sequence is empty.

You can check the whole API [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html#foldRight[B](z:B)(op:(A,B)=%3EB):B)

Answer (score 2):

Always check the excellent ScalaAPI (http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html)

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) ⇒ B): B
```

From the types you can figure it out:

a -> `A`

b -> `B`

- As you have a Stream of type `A` (`sealed trait Stream[+A]`) `a` can only be one of the elements of the Stream.
- `b` is so the value you are accumulating the result on. In `exists` it checks if one element is true for the predicate `p`.